# Почему не отображаются сообщения в чате?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Почему-то в чате, который я делаю по туториалу, после отправки не отображаются сообщения, хотя в firebase они появляются. Можете подсказать причину? Заранее спасибо.

Основной код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SIGN_IN_CODE=1;
    private RelativeLayout activity_main;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<Message> adapter;
    private FloatingActionButton sendBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==SIGN_IN_CODE) {
           if(requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
               Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Вы авторизованы", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               displayAllMessages();
               } else {
                 Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Вы не авторизованы", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 finish();
           }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity_main=findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText textField = findViewById(R.id.messageField);
                if(textField.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    return;
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new Message(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), textField.getText().toString()));
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        //Пользователь ещё не авторизован
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()==null)
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_CODE);
        //Пользователь авторизован
        else {
            Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Вы авторизованы", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            displayAllMessages();
        }
    }

    private void displayAllMessages() {
        ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
        FirebaseListOptions<Message> options =
                new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Message>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(), Message.class)
                        .setLayout(R.layout.list_item)
                        .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(options){
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
                TextView mess_user, mess_time, mess_text;
                mess_user = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                mess_time = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
                mess_text = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);

                mess_user.setText(model.getUserName());
                mess_text.setText(model.getTextMessage());
                mess_time.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };
        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Класс Message:

```
public class Message {
    private String UserName;
    private String TextMessage;
    private long MessageTime;

    public Message() {}
    public Message (String UserName, String TextMessage){
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.TextMessage = TextMessage;

        this.MessageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public String getTextMessage() {
        return TextMessage;
    }

    public void setTextMessage(String textMessage) {
        TextMessage = textMessage;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return MessageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        MessageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

Run:
[image: Run]

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь получить сообщения только после авторизации или при старте приложения и возможно получаете, но вы не подписаны на обновление в Firebase, вам нужно что-то типа этого:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Смотрите доки по Firebase.